# pywinauto: I don't see the list of items when I print_control_identifiers()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm trying to see the list of item stored in Ditto using:

```
ditto=Application().connect(path='Ditto.exe').window(title="Ditto",class_name="QPasteClass")
ditto.print_control_identifiers()
```

It prints the controls, but the list items aren't shown

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
print(ditto.print_control_identifiers())
```